# Сonvert emoji from Slack

Tags: javascript, html, slack, slack-api, emoji

I create a simple chat, using Slack API.
[Emoji received from Slack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GQaM.png)
[Emoji in Slack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFGNd.png)
From Slack I get emoji in the form **:grinning:**, **:wave:** and etc.
How can I convert this to familiar unicode to display on HTML page.
And maybe there is an opportunity to add a set of emoji for my sending to Slack in the same format.
Thank you!

Comment: Add this message as text please

Answer (score 0):

Slack emoji uses [emoji-data](https://github.com/iamcal/emoji-data) library for emoji conversion from unicode codepoint to short name and vice versa. Reference to it in Slack docs can be found [here](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#emoji).

Extract emoji short name from between colons, look up in emoji-data by `short_name` field, find `unified` field in the found object and convert hex representation from it to byte sequence which will be emoji unicode representation.